# Mutinty/Quarkus Mid Output Stream Failure Handling

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, mutiny

I'm running a quarkus server that streams large datasets to clients. During processing of a dataset, an error can occur, and I'm unsure of how to best handle the situation.

```
    @GET
    @Path("{fileName}/example")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun example(@PathParam("fileName") fileName: String): Multi<Int> {
        return Multi.createFrom().iterable((0 .. 10)).map { if (it != 4) it else throw IllegalArgumentException() }
    }
```

Without any changes, this will stream "[1,2,3" and then stop without closing the connection (CURLs hang). I can handle the issue with ".onFailure().recoverWithCompletion()", but that closes the stream in a healthy fashion (resulting in [1,2,3]). Is there any way to close the connection, but leave the response as malformed? I need a way to communicate to downstream clients that the stream of data is not healthy.

Comment: What RESTEasy extension are you using?

Comment: io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson:2.13.3.Final

Comment: Can you please open an issue on Github mentioning what you are looking for? Thanks